# Liability of substitute

Tags: halacha, time, choshen-mishpat-civil-law, employment

If someone has an appointment, and arranges for a babysitter to come to watch his/her children while he/she goes to the appointment, and the babysitter doesn't show up, so the parent misses the appointment, and needs to book and pay for a new appointment, is the babysitter liable to pay for the missed appointment? Sources please.

Comment: When the babysitter agreed to the arrangement, were they aware of the possible financial loss involved for you if they didn't show up or didn't show up on time?

Answer (score 2):

I discussed this interesting case with my rav. For now, I can supply a partial answer, as we need to research some its nuances a bit further:

When you refer to a baby-sitter, it depends if you have "hired" this person or not. I.e. - if you pay this person on "salary" for him / her to come regularly or even as needed, then that person is in the category of a "shomer sachir" - a paid watcher. That person is responsible for negligence, which MAY include such "incidental" damages as not showing up on time for the appointment and causing you a loss.

Again, we need to research further, but, I placed this as food for thought, for now.

Comment: I was actually thinking it might be similar to a shomer. But it would be good if we can find something about it from a universally accepted sefer or if you can find out if your Rav has a source. But this is good to start off with.

Answer (score 0):

*Poel yachol lachzor aphilu ad chatzi yom*. A worker can backout even mid-day. You can't buy people. However you may be able to withold wages, even beyond the missed time. checkout the 6th perek of bava metziah

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodea - the OP requested sources, which you forgot to include in your answer.